Matrix-free representation of hadamard product?
I want to compute the following expression:
$(A\odot B)v$
Where $\odot$ is matrix element-wise multiplication.
Now, I don't have access to $B$ explicitly, but I have explicit representation of $A$, in other words, suppose $B$ is inverse of a matrix ($B=C^{-1}$) that I don't want to compute it explicitly, I'm using a matrix-free method like conjugate gradient to compute $Bx$ for any vector $x$.
So I don't have $B$ explicitly, all I have is a function that computes $Bv$ for any vector $v$.
Given that, can I compute $(A\odot B)v$ for any vector $v$ ?
What I'm asking here is maybe related to propoerties of hadamard product.
I know:
\begin{equation}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vect}{vec}
(A\odot B)v = \diag(A D_v B^{T})
\end{equation}
Where $D_v$ is a diagonal matrix where $v$ is the vector as its main diagonal.
But it doesn't help me, as $A D_v$ is not a matrix-vector multiplication.

$BD_v$ is $n$ matrix-vector multiplications, i.e. one for each column of $D_v$. Similarly, $BD_vA^T$ is $n$ matrix-vector multiplications, i.e. one for each column of $D_vA^T$. I assume you need something faster than that?

@JimmyK4542 Yes, I want something faster, i.e. instead of computing $AD_v$ with $n$ matrix-vector multiplication, I'm looking to somehow relate $AD_v$ to $Av$ so at the end of the day I will be able to compute $AD_v$ with only one matrix-vector multiplication.

$
\def\h{\odot}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
$The Hadamard product distributes with respect to the standard basis vectors $\{e_k\}$.
Let $a_k=Ae_k\,$ denote the $k^{th}$ column of $A,\,$
then a Hadamard product satisfies
$$\LR{A\h B}e_k = Ae_k\h Be_k \:=\: a_k\h b_k$$
Therefore the desired product can be obtained via a vector sum
$$\eqalign{
(A\h B)\,v
 &= \LR{A\h B}\LR{\sum_k v_k\,e_k} \\ 
 &=\; {\sum_k v_k\LR{A\h B}e_k} \\
 &=\; {\sum_k v_k\LR{a_k\h b_k}} \\
}$$
